# Поиск формулы или варианты получения нужного числа из массива чисел

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение

Интересна такая задачка. Есть набор из N чисел и есть 1 число, которое нужно получить с помощью этих N чисел. Как элементарный пример, нужное число - 100 (ячейка A1), в ячейке **B1 находится число 50**, а в ячейке **C1 число 2**. Задача - узнать формулу с помощью которой можно получить число из ячейке A1 используя ячейки B1 и C1. Ответ: B1*C1; (B1/2)*(C1*2).

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В такой постановке есть бесконечное число решений, должны быть ещё какие-то ограничения.

Comment: @CrazyElf как вариант ввести ограничение вручную на 5 подобранных формул, после чего поиск завершается?

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что в текущей постановке решение будет `x = B1*C1*.../A1`, и это будет коэффициент при `B1`, например, а дальше можно брать любое ненулевое число `k`, домножать на него `x` и тогда у `C1` будет коэффициент `1/k`.

Comment: Если уж у вас написано машинное обучение в тегах, то машинное обучение - это когда дано много строк с такими числами и решениями и нужно вычислить такие коэффициенты, которые дадут, например, наименьшее среднеквадратичное отклонение по всем таким строкам. Вот это уже понятная задача, решаемая обычной линейной регрессией, но только если всё это складывается `Bn*k1+Cn*k2+.. = An`, а не перемножается.

Comment: @CrazyElf таких строк около 1000 - это финансовые показатели компаний. А число которое нужно получить - это стоимость акции. Просто складывать - не вариант. Я просто хотел узнать возможно ли вообще такое сделать с помощью pandas, например. В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Смотреть в сторону задачи регрессии. Методов миллион, начиная с линейной регрессии. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html